# Load previous android Project fails

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've set up new windows os: 10

after installing android studio and create a new one it works well but when trying to open existing project I get an error with

> A problem occurred configuring project  ':app'.

I've made sure that the old project has the same gradle configs as the new one.

can anyone help?

this is the exception I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:782)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getPlatformVersion(NdkHandler.java:158)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.supports64Bits(NdkHandler.java:331)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getDefaultAbis(NdkHandler.java:412)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.create(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:736)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createExternalNativeBuildJsonGenerators(TaskManager.java:1711)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.lambda$createTasksForVariantScope$10(ApplicationTaskManager.java:210)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager$$Lambda$205/636103725.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantScope(ApplicationTaskManager.java:205)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:530)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createAndroidTasks$1(VariantManager.java:352)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$$Lambda$145/195502090.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:348)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:751)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$$Lambda$103/1684325025.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:746)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$$Lambda$79/338632383.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
```

**Update 1**: the old project contains dependencies like retrofit

**Update 2**: I've installed Android SDK and android project in partition E

Comment: you probably need to upgrade its gradle etc if you were using an old Android studio before. Try opening the build.gradle and syncing

Comment: @Doomsknight I did and changed it's gradle wit same I get from new project to meet same versions but fails too

Comment: make sure the `buildToolsVersion ` installed in new android studio.

Comment: installed it works in new projects well